In React, I can store my data in LocalStorage via JSON, but can't seem to pull it out on reload
I manage to put the data item into JSON, but on useEffect, on reload, the item somewhat reloads, but it always gets rewritten, and I get red line under (localStorage.getItem('chatLInes')) part and this warning when I hover over it:

Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of
type 'string'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string

this is the snippet:
 useEffect(() => {
        setChatLInes(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chatLInes')) ?? []);
    }, []);

    const makeUser = (user: any) => setUser(user);
    const makeMessages = (messages: any) => {
        setMessages(messages);

        let tempChatLInes: any = [];
        messages.map((message: any) => {
            let chatLIne = { userName: '', color: '', message: '' };
            chatLIne.userName = user.userName;
            chatLIne.color = user.color;
            chatLIne.message = message;
            tempChatLInes.push(chatLIne);
            return tempChatLInes;
        });

        changeChatLines(tempChatLInes);
        setChatLInes(tempChatLInes);
        console.log(chatLines);
    };
    const changeChatLines = (chatLines: any) =>
        localStorage.setItem('chatLInes', JSON.stringify(chatLines));

I put localstorage part under a separate variable, dwabble in typescript attributes, turn off jslint because I thought it was a typescript thing, make a separate function that deals with putting into localstorage. results are the same with same warning

You don't need an effect to get the value from localStorage and you can pass the string '[]' to JSON.parse when there is no value stored in localStorage to fix the TypeScript error.
const [chatLines, setChatLines] = useState(
           () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chatLInes') ?? '[]'));


Thank you very much, it worked. I just had to put [] under quotation marks. But I dont understand why that worked? I have the  same JSON get and set item with localstorage  in another react program without the quotation marks and it works.
I don't get it. Why is that? Is it bc the other program doesn't have typscript?

@DankoGrgić It's just a TypeScript error. It doesn't prevent your code from working even if you ignore it.

thanx, i found a better workaround where you just put an "!" on the end of JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chatLInes'), . that way you need no quotation marks on the end parenthesis

@DankoGrgić That's not a better solution. ! is non-null assertion and that's just lying to TypeScript as localStorage.getItem can return null. TypeScript expects the argument to JSON.parse to be a string, so just accept that. If you're going to use TypeScript, use it properly instead of trying to just circumvent its type system.

I have a pretty similar code to the one i just sent here, also in react. In that one i didn't have to put [] under quotation marks and JSON parsing in that one works perfectly. Why is that?

@DankoGrgić Were you using TypeScript? TypeScript expects that the argument to JSON.parse be exactly of type string.
